# Regex to String generation

Tags: java, strings, regular-expressions

Let's say that we have a regex and an index `i`.  If we suppose that the set of strings that match our regex are sorted in a lexicographical order, how could we get the `i` element of this list?

**Edit :** I added this simple example for more explanation:

**input :**

```
regex="[a-c]{1,2}";
index=4;
```

In this case the ordered list of strings that this regex matches contains the following  elements:

```
a
aa
ab
ac
b
ba
bb
bc
c
ca
cb
cc
```

**output :**

The 4th element, which is **ac**

ps: It's known that a given regex could match an infinite number of strings.  This shouldn't have an impact on the process of extracting the element in the given finite `index`.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: First question should be: *Can* we define such a list? With S-> aS|b, `b` index would be "Infinite"

Comment: Correction, I used a grammar description (even if the expression itself is a regex)... maybe it would be more familiar to you as `a*b`

Comment: Could you show what you are intending with a trivial example and its solution? Preferably, one example with and one without the Kleene star.  You might want to consider restricting the regular language further to the finite languages and star-free languages.

Comment: @MichaelT check the edit i have added an example.

Comment: @SJuan76 i know , this should not have any impact  , at least we have to avoid any strategy that try to generate all possibilities  that matches the regex.

Comment: How do you know, that you can exclude `String`s having a length of more than two `char`s? Unless you know beforehand, between each two adjacent matches lies an quasi-infinite number of `String` candidates to test…

Comment: Are you sure the lexicographical ordering is a useful one? I think you can build a regular language in which, following the lexicographical ordering you cannot reach certain words of the language in a finite number of steps. E.g. the language of strings with an arbitrary number of `a` followed by an optional `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kevin's answer was a good start to know how we can deal with regular expression from a theoritical point of view, which would help  building a java library that let users generate String based on a given regex . Here is a what i've build , a [java library](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex) that provide many features for using regex to generate String (random generation ,generate String based on it's index, generate all String..) check it out [here](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex) .

Example :

```
    Generex generex = new Generex("[0-3]([a-c]|[e-g]{1,2})");

    // generate the second String in lexicographical order that match the given Regex.
    String secondString = generex.getMatchedString(2);
    System.out.println(secondString);// it print '0b'

    // Generate all String that matches the given Regex.
    List<String> matchedStrs = generex.getAllMatchedStrings();

    // Using Generex iterator
    Iterator iterator = generex.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
    }
    // it print 0a 0b 0c 0e 0ee 0e 0e 0f 0fe 0f 0f 0g 0ge 0g 0g 1a 1b 1c 1e
    // 1ee 1e 1e 1f 1fe 1f 1f 1g 1ge 1g 1g 2a 2b 2c 2e 2ee 2e 2e 2f 2fe 2f 2f 2g
    // 2ge 2g 2g 3a 3b 3c 3e 3ee 3e 3e 3f 3fe 3f 3f 3g 3ge 3g 3g 1ee

    // Generate random String
    String randomStr = generex.random();
    System.out.println(randomStr);// a random value from the previous String list
```

Comment: Generates empty list for "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}"     and throws StackOverflowError  for "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\W).{8,})".  Both are patterns to generate password with at least 8 characters .It contains at least 2 numbers, 1 symbol, 1 lower case characters

Answer (score 6):

A regular expression maps directly to a finite state machine.  Generating strings from the FSM is straightforward with a backtracking algorithm.  The example is for the regular expression /aa?b/

```
(start) 0 -- a --> 1 -- a --> 2 -- b --> 3 (accepting and terminal)
                   |                     ^
                   |---------b ----------|

State   Previous char   Input char    Input string     History
  0        null                           --             []
                            a              a         
  1        null                                        [{a,1}]
                            a              aa          [{a,1},{a,2}]
  2        null
                            b             aab          [{a,1},{a,2},{b,3}]
  3        null
         Accepting state, emit 'aab' as valid input
         Terminal state, backtrack
  2          b                             aa          [{a,1},{a,2}]
         No further valid inputs, backtrack
  1          a                             a           [{a,1}]
                            b              ab
  3        null                                        [{a,1},{b,3}]
         Accepting state, emit 'ab' as valid input
         Terminal state, backtrack
  1          b                             a           [{a,1}]
         No further valid inputs, backtrack
  0          a                             --          []
         No further valid inputs, stack empty, terminate
```

Comment: It seems that this is useful , i already found a [Java package](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/automaton/) that use finit state automata  to do operation on regular expression, maybe i have to extend this work to achieve the objective.

Comment: Are the strings generated by the finite state machine in lexicographical order?

Comment: @Giorgio: yes, if you take the legal transitions at each state in collating order.  The previously tried inputs are recorded, to after backtracking you just take the next legal character after the one previously used.

Comment: @kevincline check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

On their own, regexes are serving the purpose of answering the question: "Given this **list** of strings as input and this pattern, which subset mathces it?". It does not work backwards i.e. from this regex, start generating strings that match it.

Having said that, take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/xeger/, that is supposed to do what you want to achieve (with some limitations as described in https://code.google.com/p/xeger/wiki/XegerLimitations).

If your regex is accepted, I guess the anwer to your question is pretty straightforward i.e. generate the list and take the item at index `i`

Comment: _xeger_  just generate a **random** string that match your regex, and hwo tell you that regex : 'It does not work backwards' ?? check [this](http://regldg.com/) online regular expression grammar language dictionary generator, it does the job . but we are looking here for idea that help building similar tools.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose this answer just in case it can help you some how.
In case there are some details or some small errors, please leave comment.
I will try to correct.

1. First look at the minimum finite state automata FSA of the regex
2. Find the first matching string of the FSA. This can be done by creating an auxiliary FSA in which you remove all paths leading to the reject state, then start walking through the auxiliary FSA. At each transition, choose the first character from the input alphabet to make sure you generate the first matching string.
3. Now we need to get the second matching string of the original regex, so we modify the auxiliary FSA so that in the final state (before the accep state), the last character input (of the first matching string in 2 above) would not lead to the accept state. This can be done by removing an edge (and a state) or modify the edge leading to the accepting state.
4. Generate the first matching string of the modified auxiliary FSA, this would give you the second matching string of the original regex
5. Repeat modifying the auxiliary FSA until you get to the i-th matching string. This would be the i-the matching string of the original regex.